# iTextSharp - appending document as a page

Tags: pdf, itext

So far with iTextSharp, I've been able to create a pdf using Adobe Acrobat Pro with text fields. I'm able to open the PDF using iTextSharp then populate the desired fields with the key information into the key fields.

Next, I'm able to wrap everything up and send the file out from a byte array as a file attachment - so everything works good.

The problem lies in this - I have to create a PDF document in the memory stream and flood the document with the necessary text. I've gotten that down fairly well.

The problem is that I'm confused as to how I can append that document in the memory stream to the existing source .PDF that sits in the file stream as a **new page.**

One is to use stamper.insert page but I struggle with the idea that I cannot add headers to the rectangle and I'm thinking that using Document doc = new Document() is the way to go.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please rephrase your question using pseudocode involving names such as emptyform.pdf, filledoutform.pdf, existingdocument.pdf. Without extra info it's not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: Have you considered using PdfConcatenate? You can use PdfConcatenate to produce a concatenated document in any stream, memory or file system, and the source documents are required in the form of PdfReaders which also can be instantiated from file system (by file name) or from memory (as a byte array which can be tretrieved from a MemoryStream). If you supply the (pseudo)code Bruno asked for, this can be elaborated.

Comment: Here's the pseudo code code:

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code code. This is what it currently does.

Open source file and store into byte[]
Populate text fields in the pdf using .SetField using Acrofields (this is successful)
Stamp and close
Return as a byte array and send it off as a file attachment. This all works just fine.

Now - we need to attach a new page to the above existing document with text - several paragraphs.

Create a memory stream
Create a document
Create a writer and blend memory stream and document together.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
doc.Open();
doc.NewPage();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Chunk(complaintinfo.COMPLAINT_DESC, new Font(Font.NORMAL, qSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)));
// doc - add header info later..
doc.Add(p);
```

How do I add the doc as an new page to the existing .pdf that is already in the file stream? Naturally, I'm assuming we want to add the page before we stamp and close the reader that is linked to the original PDF.